# ERC2981 royalties rounding issue

Tags: solidity, royalties, eip-2981

I have recently been developing a smart contract that implements the ERC2981 (https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2981) token standard.

The `royaltyInfo` function I implement abides to the standard, getting royalties on a per token basis. Here is the function.

```
function royaltyInfo(uint256 tokenId, uint256 value)
    external
    view
    override
    returns (address receiver, uint256 royaltyAmount)
{
    RoyaltyInfo memory royalties = _royalties[tokenId];
    receiver = royalties.recipient;
    royaltyAmount = (value * royalties.amount) / 10000;
}
```

The issue is that when I have some royalty amounts, the amount returned is rounded down.

For example, if the royalties amount for a token is 50 (which is 0.5% royalties), and the `value` param I enter into the function is 1000, then 5 is returned. This is the correct value.

However when I enter 100 as the `value` param, then 0 is returned, when 0.5 is the correct value.

Is there anyway to return the correct value whilst still abiding to the ERC2981 token standard?

If not, is there a solution to avoid people not receiving royalties like in the above example, and how would you implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading from the EIP:

> The percentage value used must be independent of the sale price for reasons previously mentioned (i.e. if the percentage value 10%, then 10% MUST apply whether _salePrice is 10, 10000 or 1234567890). If the royalty fee calculation results in a remainder, implementers MAY round up or round down to the nearest integer. For example, if the royalty fee is 10% and _salePrice is 999, the implementer can return either 99 or 100 for royaltyAmount, both are valid.

So rounding up is acceptable and you can do it like this:

```js
// return royaltyAmount rounded up
function royaltyInfo(uint256 tokenId, uint256 value)
    external
    view
    override
    returns (address receiver, uint256 royaltyAmount)
{
    RoyaltyInfo memory royalties = _royalties[tokenId];
    receiver = royalties.recipient;

    uint256 tmp = value * royalties.amount;
    if (tmp == 0) {
        royaltyAmount = 0;
    } else {
        royaltyAmount = (tmp - 1) / 10000 + 1;
    }
}
```

Generally however a marketplace would use a token with a lot of decimals (WETH has 18, USDC has 6). In this case, the last digit of the value isn't that important, that's why people generally round down.